# Minecraft Input Bug(It's not glfw #1112)

Tags: minecraft

I have a keyboard input bug in Minecraft 1.12 and below. When I open a world I can use only number keys, arrows and special keys(functional keys, escape etc).
I wrote a mod that writes the name and code of the button when it is pressed and it does not respond to press on buttons with letters on they.
I think Minecraft response buttons wrong.

My system: Fedora 35, KDE Plasma 5.24.3, X11 1.20.14

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it and I hope somebody can help me

Comment: A bit of a wild guess here, but what keyboard layout do you use? Some software is known to not handle non-Latin layouts properly.

Comment: I use english qwerty and sometimes russian. But when I launch Minecraft I use english

Comment: Addition: Minecraft response letter keys but when I release a key it does not response.

Comment: In Minecraft options file default binding to forward is W(key code is 17 that matches to keycode in LWJGL), but if I change forward to W on keyboard key code will be 375.